# How to populate Relationships

Tags: custom-fields, mysql, relationships

I'd like to manually populate the relationships table with some data.

I can see the structure of the exp_relationships table, which relates parent_entries to children.

However, for a custom field set that has multiple relationships, I cannot see how EE ties the relationships to each custom relationship field.

It looks like there was a handy wiki for this exact task linked from here which EL have removed in the recent reshuffle: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/165752/

Other than populating the exp_relationships table, how can I relate those relationships to specific custom fields?

EDIT: Oh man - I cannot believe I've been so stupid - of course the relationship ID is tied to the relevant CF column in exp_channel_data!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you sorted this out, but for others who may wind up here looking for details:

Say you have an entry with an `entry_id` of `10`. That entry's channel has a Relationship field with a `field_id` of `20`.

While editing that entry, you choose a child entry from your Relationship field, which has an `entry_id` of `50`.

You'll end up with these values in your database:

**exp_relationships**
`rel_id`: 1 (incremental number generated each time a new relationship is created)
`rel_parent_id`: 10 (the entry you were editing)
`rel_child_id`: 50 (the entry you chose in the Relationship field)

**exp_channel_data**
`entry_id`: 10 (the entry you were editing)
`field_id_20`: 1 (the `rel_id` that was created above)

Comment: For the record, posting a solution and accepting your own answer is totally fine (you won't earn rep from it anyway). In this case Derek's answer is much more thorough though.

Answer (score 1):

Oh man - I cannot believe I've been so stupid - of course the relationship ID is tied to the relevant CF column in exp_channel_data!